# Is there any simpler way to write a program showing the number of days in a month

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm asked to solve a Python exercise as follows:

> Write a program to check an input from the user.
>
> - If that input is not a month, then ask the user to reenter the month.
> - If that input is February, ask the user what the year is then print out the number of days in that February based on whether or not it is a leap year.
> - If that input is not February, then print out the number of days in that month.

I can solve this problem and below is my code.

```py
valid_months = ['january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december']
month = input('Please insert a month: ').lower()

if month == 'february':
    year = int(input('Please insert a year: '))
    if (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0):
        print('This is February in a leap year and has 29 days.')
    else:
        print('This is February in a normal year and has 28 days.')
elif month in valid_months:
    days_in_month = {
        'january': 31,
        'february': 28,
        'march': 31,
        'april': 30,
        'may': 31,
        'june': 30,
        'july': 31,
        'august': 31,
        'september': 30,
        'october': 31,
        'november': 30,
        'december': 31
    }
    print(f'There are {days_in_month[month]} days in {month.capitalize()}.')
else:
    print('Invalid month. Please enter a valid month.')
```

However, I found that my code is complicated since it contains a dictionary. I wonder if there is simpler solution for this problem.

Feel free to comment, answer if you found any simpler solution. That would be helpful and highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Does the exercise allow you to use the `datetime` module?

Comment: "my code is complicated since it contains a dictionary" - there is nothing complicated about dictionaries. If anything, I would say the code is too simple because it hard-codes the results in a dictionary.

Comment: You just do exactly what the exercise asks for. The only thing you could change is to delete `'february'` from the dictionary, since you handle this case in your if statement.

Comment: About coding homework / assignments / contests: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/12846804)

Comment: Thanks everyone for explaining. This is not a homework or assignment or a problem in a contest. I'm learning Python on my own, so I always want to check whether there is a way to solve any problem without using complicated tool. The code works, but I do want to know whether my algorithm is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is not complicated because it contains a dictionary, it is complicated because it does not use the dictionary more.

Assuming that you are not allowed to use `datetime`, you can simplify quite a bit:

```py
days_in_month = {
    "january": 31,
    "february": 28,
    "march": 31,
    "april": 30,
    "may": 31,
    "june": 30,
    "july": 31,
    "august": 31,
    "september": 30,
    "october": 31,
    "november": 30,
    "december": 31,
}
# Because you already have the months in the dictionary, you do not need valid_months.
month = input("Please insert a month: ").lower()

if month in days_in_month:
    is_leap_feb = False
    if month == "february":
        year = int(input("Please insert a year: "))
        is_leap_feb = (year % 4 == 0 and year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)

    print(f"There are {29 if is_leap_feb else days_in_month[month]} days in {month.capitalize()}.")
else:
    print("Invalid month. Please enter a valid month.")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import calendar
Month=input(" enter month ")
Year=2001 # default year but you can choose any
if Month.capitalize()=='February':    
      Year=int(input('Enter Year '))    
    print(calendar.monthrange(Year,list(calendar.month_name).index(Month.capitalize()))[1])    
else:     
    print(calendar.monthrange(Year,list(calendar.month_name).index(Month.capitalize()))[1])
```

---

#this is how to you should code to get the right answer with short format of code but you have to import 'calendar' to use the above code ##

Comment: Thank you. I don't know the existence of 'calendar'. The problem just popped out of my mind, and I try to solve it.